# pandas Groupby Aggregate add summary rows

Tags: pandas-groupby

Loving Pandas - and especially the groupby function. Currently it can group the raw data and summarise the data very well, with nested breakdowns ( ie Cat1, Cat, Brand as per the below )

Question is, I would like summary rows for each nested level, including a final total, and can't figure out how to do it. Been looking at code everywhere - exhausted by Google search

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
salesdata = pd.read_csv("data/junk.csv")
dfa=salesdata.groupby(['cat1','cat2','brand']).aggregate({'gmv':    ['sum']})
dfa.to_excel('junk_summary.xlsx', sheet_name='summary')
```

Sorry - tried to show in this screen the output format, cant seem to get it to work so made images

[Current Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfIfb.png)
[Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLfPC.png)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is

1. calculate sum table (table1) for groupby([cat1, cat2]) and name the sum column “gmv”
2. calculate another sum table (table2) for groupby([cat1]) and again name the sum column “gmv”
3. Outer merge your table with table1 on [cat1, cat2, gmv] -> table3
4. Outer merge table3 with table2 on [cat1, gmv]

It wouldn’t exactly look like what you want but should be pretty close. If there are NA values from the merge, you can do df.fillna(“”).

Comment: Thanks Tim, I am quite new to Python, but get your gist - will spend some time playing with it